# Insert rows with conditions with Pentaho Spoon

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have to do a process with Pentaho spoon and I'm stuck. I think it has to be something simple and I hope you can help me.

I start from a table that has some multivalued fields that are separated by a comma. What I want is to create a table with the ID field and separate the multi-valued in the corresponding rows, inserting new ones but keeping the ID field. And then have a weight field in which 1 is divided by the number of rows each ID has.

It would be something like this:

```
ID  TYPE    MATERIAL    PERSON
1   2444    MATERM0140  A,B
2   2444,1555   WATER00000114   C
3   2444    WATER00000016   D
4   2444    WATER00000970   D
5   2444    MATERM0180  C
6   2444,1555   WATER00000490   A,E
7   2444,1555   WATER00000645   E
8   2444    WATER00000900   B
```

And it would have the resulting tables:

```
ID  PERSON  PONDERACION
1   A   0,5
1   B   0,5
2   C   1
3   D   1
4   D   1
5   C   1
6   A   0,5
6   E   0,5
7   E   1
8   B   1


ID  TYPE    PONDERACION
1   2444    1
2   2444    0,5
2   1555    0,5
3   2444    1
4   2444    1
5   2444    1
6   2444    0,5
6   1555    0,5
7   2444    0,5
7   1555    0,5
8   2444    1
```

Can you help me with this? Thank you!! ^^